# Issue Enabling Microsoft Teams Security Preview

Tags: powershell, microsoft-teams

I'm currently facing an issue while attempting to enable Microsoft Teams Security Preview using PowerShell. When I run the command:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> Set-TeamsSecurityPreview -Enable $true
```

I encounter the following error:

```
Set-TeamsSecurityPreview : The term 'Set-TeamsSecurityPreview' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function,
script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ Set-TeamsSecurityPreview -Enable $true
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Set-TeamsSecurityPreview:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

I've ensured that I'm running the command as an administrator and that I've installed the required modules and dependencies, but I still can't seem to resolve this issue.

[image: I connect with the exchange and then tried the command to enable the Teams preview on MS 365.]

Comment: Are you logged in as a user that has the correct permissions to run that command on Exchange Online?

Comment: Yes, I am running cmd as an admin and logging in exchange online as a root.